# Change function jquery didn't send value to views.py (didn't work)

Tags: jquery, html, django

So I want to make a 2 dropdown but second dropdown dependent on  the value on the first dropdown

HTML code for the select dropdown option

```html
<form class="form-horizontal  style-form" action="#">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label col-md-3">Database Name</label>
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker">
                      <div class="btn-group">
                            <select id="tableselect" style="width:425px;background-color:white;height:30px;">              
                            <!-- <li><a href="#"></a></li> -->
                               {% for table_name in obj %}
                                <option value="{{table_name.table_name}}">{{ table_name.table_name }}
                              {% endfor %}                          
                            <!-- <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a></li> -->
                            </option>
                            </select>                    
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label col-md-3">Table Name</label>
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker">
                       <div class="btn-group">
                            <select id ="dataselect" style="width:425px;background-color:white;height:30px;font-color:red;text-align-last:center;">              


                            </select>                    
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
</form>
{% block extrajs %}

  #all the js script source I put here 

  <script>
  $(document).ready(function()
  {
    $('#tableselect').change(function() {
      var url = "{% static url 'load-data' %}";
      var table_name = $(this).val();
      $.ajax({
        url : url,
        data : {
          'table_name' = table_name
        },
        success : function(data){
          $('#dataselect').html(data);
        }
      });
    });
  });
  </script>
  {% endblock  %}
```

`views.py` where I put the process the request here

```py
def load_data(request):
    table_name = request.GET.get('table_name')
    dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn('ip', 'port', sid=' ')
    conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user=r'', password='', dsn=dsn_tns)
    c = conn.cursor()
    obj2 = c.execute ('SELECT table_name FROM ALL_TABLES WHERE owner = '+table_name+'')
    context = {
        'obj2' : obj2
    }
    return render(request,data_list.html,context)
```

`data_list.html` where the **ajax** takes the HTML to put in the base HTML

```html
{% block extrajs %}
{% endblock  %}

{% for data in obj2 %}
<option value="{{ data.table_name }}">{{ data.table_name }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

seems like when I choose the selected value, it won't send any parameter to jquery or to views, maybe the change function didn't work?? can someone help

Comment: this might help you https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html

Comment: @flaxon thankyou , i will read it first

Comment: try removing from `{% block extrajs %}`
`{% endblock  %}` from data_list.html

Answer (score 0):

```
In your javascript section, you have to do like this:-

<script>
  $(document).ready(function()
  {
    $('#tableselect').change(function() {
      var url = "{% static url 'load-data' %}";
      var table_name = $(this).val();
      $.ajax({
        url : url,
        data : {
          'table_name' = table_name
        },
        success : function(data){
            for(i=0; i<data['obj2'].length; i++){
                $('#dataselect').append('<option>'+obj2[i]+'</option>');
            }
        }
      });
    });
  });
  </script>
```